# Substring until end of the character

Tags: c#, .net

How can I substring a character until the end of the text which the length of the string always changes? I need to get everything after the ABC
The samples are:

```
ABC123
ABC13245
ABC123456
ABC1
```

Answer (score 18):

```
string search = "ABC"; 
string result = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(search) + search.Length);
```

Comment: or "ABC".Length instead of 3

Comment: The `IndexOf` is necessary only if the string starts with something other than `"ABC"`. It isn't a lot of overhead, though, and does answers the question.

Comment: I tried this but it returns null value ""    this.TextBox1.Text.Trim().Substring(this.TextBox1.Text.Trim().IndexOf("ABC") + this.TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length)

Answer (score 10):

## Answer

```
var startIndex = "ABC".Length;
var a = "ABC123".Substring(startIndex); // 123
var b = "ABC13245".Substring(startIndex); // 13245
var c = "ABC123456".Substring(startIndex); // 123456
car d = "ABC1".Substring(startIndex); // 1
```

## Remarks

#### With `Substring()` - Faster

[string.Substring(int startIndex)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns all the characters after `startIndex`. Here it is as a method you can use.

```
public static string SubstringAfter(string s, string after)
{
    return s.Substring(after.Length);
}
```

#### With `Remove()` - Slightly Slower

[string.Remove(int start, int count)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a new string after removing `count` characters beginning with the character at index `start`.

```
public static string SubstringAfter(string s, string after)
{
    return s.Remove(0, after.Length);
}
```

#### With `Substring()` and `IndexOf()` - Slower Still

If your string started with something other than `ABC`, and if you wanted to get everything after `ABC`, then, as Greg rightly answered, you would use `IndexOf()`.

```
var s = "123ABC456";
var result = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("ABC") + "ABC".Length)); // 456
```

#### [Proof](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DBWa2M)

Here's a demo, which also shows which is fastest.

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = "ABC123".Substring("ABC".Length);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine("---");

        Test(SubstringAfter_Remove);
        Test(SubstringAfter_Substring);
        Test(SubstringAfter_SubstringWithIndexOf);
    }

    public static void Test(Func<string, string, string> f)
    {
        var array = 
            new string[] { "ABC123", "ABC13245", "ABC123456", "ABC1" };

        var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        foreach(var s in array) {
            Console.WriteLine(f.Invoke(s, "ABC"));
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(f.Method.Name + " : " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks.");
        Console.WriteLine("---");
    }

    public static string SubstringAfter_Remove(string s, string after)
    {
        return s.Remove(0, after.Length);
    }

    public static string SubstringAfter_Substring(string s, string after)
    {
        return s.Substring(after.Length);       
    }

    public static string SubstringAfter_SubstringWithIndexOf(string s, string after)
    {
        return s.Substring(s.IndexOf(after) + after.Length);        
    }    
}
```

Output

```
123
---
123
13245
123456
1
SubstringAfter_Remove : 2616 ticks.
---
123
13245
123456
1
SubstringAfter_Substring : 2210 ticks.
---
123
13245
123456
1
SubstringAfter_SubstringWithIndexOf : 2748 ticks.
---
```